# PHP - Form data transfer and Retrieve Result - with out HTML Form

Tags: php, forms, post

This is the form

```
<form method="POST" action="https://secure.ebs.in/api/1_0"
name="frmTransaction">
<input name="Action" type="hidden" value="statusByRef">
<input name="AccountID" type="hidden" value="XXXX">
<input name="SecretKey" type="hidden" value="XXXXXX">
<input name="RefNo" type="hidden" value="XXXXX">
<input name="submitted" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form >
```

The output will be in the following format

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<output transactionId="2144154" paymentId="1112034" amount="1" dateTime="2010-07-
31 16:59:28" mode="TEST" referenceNo="223" transactionType="Authorized"
status="Processed" isFlagged="NO"/>
```

**Now i need the output by only using php.**

How can i transfer the form data in POST method without using html?

Comment: You failed. Try to ask your question again, in a more sensible form

Comment: How do you mean transfer the form data in POST without using html? Do you mean like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

Comment: I am looking for a solution like HTTP request or sockets. I cannot use html because i am trying to get the status of the transaction using php

Answer (score 0):

PHP CURL might be what you exactly need.

check it out here : 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

and here is a tutorial to get you started :
http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl